# I am unable to save the details when clicked Add button in EventForm page must display in EventList page in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

Unable to display the text entered in the Eventform and show it on the flatlist of EventList page.I am new to react native just need some help to solve the problem. Learning to develop a notes application.

EventForm js I am entering the text in it which has name location and notes field but when press add button does not showing it in the flatlist.

```
class EventForm extends Component {

    state = {
        title: null,
        date: '',
    };
    handleAddPress = () => {
     saveevents(this.state)
    //    console.log('saving events:', this.state);
          .then(()=> this.props.navigation.goBack());
    }
    // handlePress() {
    //     this.props.onBtnPress()
    //   }
    // }

    handleChangeTitle = (text) => {
        this.setState({ title: text });
    }
    handleChangeLocation =(text) => {
        this.setState({location: text});
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1
                }}
            >
                <View style={styles.fieldContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.text}
                        placeholder="Name"
                        spellCheck={false}
                        value={this.state.title}
                        onChangeText={this.handleChangeTitle}

                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.text}
                        placeholder="Enter your Location"
                        spellCheck={false}
                        value={this.state.location}
                        onChangeText={this.handleChangeLocation}

                    />
                    <AutoExpandingTextInput
                        placeholder="Write your Notes here"
                        spellCheck={false}
                        style={[styles.default, {height: Math.max(35, this.state.height)}]}
                        value={this.state.text}
                    />
                </View>
                <TouchableHighlight
                onPress ={() =>this.handleAddPress.bind(this)}
                    // onPress={this.handleAddPress}
                    style={styles.button}

                >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>
```

EventList js where I would like to display the dynamic text entered in EventForm should appear in flatlist. I am saving the flatlist content in db json file and calling it in the EventList.

```
     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          list: {
            flex: 1,
            paddingTop: 20,
            backgroundColor: '#A9A9A9'

          },

        });

        class EventList extends Component {
          state = {
            events: [],
          }
          componentDidMount() {

             //getEvents().then(events => this.setState({ events }));

            const events = require('./db.json').events;
            this.setState({ events });

          }

          render() {
            return [

              <FlatList
                key="flatlist"
                style={styles.list}
                data={this.state.events}
                renderItem={({ item, seperators }) => (<EventCard events= 
 {item} />)}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

              />,
```

My db json file is this which I have manually entered the details.Data that is dynamically entered have to save in db json file and should reflect in the flatlist.

```
        {
            "events":[
                {
                    "name":"chandu",
                    "date":"15-06-2018 ",
                    "location":"Sydney",
                    "content":"How are you..?",
                    "id":"05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039144"
                },
                {
                    "name":"bread",
                    "date":"15-07-2018 ",
                    "location":"Sydney",
                    "content":"I bought bread..?",
                    "id":"05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039145"
                }
        ]
        }
```

I am expecting whatever the text that is entered in the form should save and show me on the Flatlist which is in EventList file. Please help if you get any solution for it.

I have added alert message when onPressed to show that whether it is pressed or not.

I am expecting whatever the text that is entered in the form should save and show me on the Flatlist which is in EventList file. Please help if you get any solution for it.
I have added alert message when onPressed to show that whether it is pressed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EventForm` and `EventList` are two separate component without any shared props.

Assuming you are updating `db.json` file (using file read/write methods) from `EventsForm` component, still in the `EventsList` the data is fetched only once on `componentDidMount`.

You will need to pass the data for `EventList` as props or keep in state. If you keep it in props, then you must update the value of state using some life cycle method such as `getDerivedStateFromProps` props or something similar.

**Edit**: 
I would suggest using global state management library like [redux](https://redux.js.org/), for saving your data entered in the `EventForm` component, instead of read/write in a file.

You can save the data by dispatching an `action` in your `EventForm` component.
Later access that data in you `EventList` component using

```
this.props.your_db_name
```

You can save this data even on app kill using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

If you still want to continue with file read/write, you can look at this library [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/)

Comment: Thank you @NishantNair.
Can you please explain in detail about how to apply within my code.

Comment: Thank you @NishanthNair. But in my project I am not using Redux. Is it possible to retrieve the data on the EventList without using Redux. If there is any way please inform.